# Can someone give more information regarding Heramba Ganapati?

Tags: ganesha

There is only one shloka mentioning Heramba Ganapati. Are there several shlokas for Heramba Ganapati?
Also does anyone have a correct image of Heramba Ganapati which matches the correct description?

I am trying to buy photo of Heramba Ganapathi and unable to find a correct image.

Answer (score 1):

[Heramba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heramba) (Sanskrit: हेरम्ब, Heraṃba), also known as **Heramba Ganapati** (Heraṃba-gaṇapati), is a five-headed iconographical form of the Hindu god Ganesha (Ganapati). This form is particularly popular in Nepal. This form is important in Tantric worship of Ganesha. He is one of the most popular of the thirty-two forms of Ganesha.

---

[image]

### [image]

The following **heramba** stotraM is from Mudala puranam, which is a Upa Purana. Most of the upa puranas are available in Sanskrit only.

### || herambastotraM gaurikRRitam || (source: [Mudgala Puranam](https://stotram.co.in/heramba-stotram-gowri-krutha/))

shrI gaNeshAya namaH |
gauryuvAcha |
gajAnana j~nAnavihArakArinna mAM cha jAnAsi parAvamarShAm |
gaNesha rakShasva na chechCharIraM tyajAmi sadyastvayi bhaktiyuktA || 1||

vighnesha heramba mahodara priya lambodara premavivardhanAchyuta |
vighnasya hartA.asurasa~NghahartA mAM rakSha daityAtvayi bhaktiyuktAm || 2||

kiM siddhibuddhiprasareNa mohayukto.asi kiM vA nishi nidrito.asi |
kiM lakShalAbhArthavichArayuktaH kiM mAM cha vismRRitya susaMsthito.asi || 3||

kiM bhaktasa~Ngena cha devadeva nAnopachAraishcha suyantrito.asi |
kiM modakArthe gaNapAddhRRito.asi nAnAvihAreShu cha vakratuNDa || 4||

svAnandabhogeShu parihRRito.asi dAsIM cha vismRRitya mahAnubhAva |
AnantyalIlAsu cha lAlaso.asi kiM bhaktarakShArthasusa~NkaTasthaH || 5||

aho gaNeshAmRRitapAnadakShAmaraistathA vA.asurapaiH smRRito.asi |
tadarthanAnAvidhisaMyuto.asi visRRijya mAM dAsImananyabhAvAm || 6||

rakShasva mAM dInatamAM paresha sarvatra chitteShu cha saMsthitastvam |
prabho vilambena vinAyako.asi brahmesha kiM deva namo namaste || 7||

bhaktAbhimAnIti cha nAma mukhyaM vede tvabhAvAn nahi chenmahAtman |
Agatya hatvA.aditijaM suresha mAM rakSha dAsIM hRRidi pAdaniShThAm || 8||

aho na dUraM tava ki~nchideva kathaM na buddhIsha samAgato.asi |
suchintyadeva prajahAmi dehaM yashaH kariShye viparItamevam || 9||

Comment: ty for the information regarding heramba stotram.
The correct sanskrit version is at
https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_ganesha/gaurikRitaMherambastotram.pdf

But unfortunately it doesn't have the meaning along with it.

The images are not correct.
First image does not have lion as vahana,
Second image also has the items missing.

I am yet to find a correct image of Heramba Ganapathy

Comment: Ty for mudgala purana stotram. 
Just mentioning the name of stotram was enough. 
But the images seem to be wrong. They do not seem to fit the description aka they do not have the correct weapons/objects in the 10 hands. For example the first sculpture doesn't have a lion has the asana.

the ten hands have following postures/items

1. Abhaya 
2. Varada
3. Pasha (Noose)
4. Danta (Tusk)
5. Akshamala
6. Elephant goad
7. axe
8. mallet
9. modak
10. phalam fruit aka wood apple